# jQuery does not loading data after click on link

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am facing problem with jquery data load. i have menu and i just want what?
when i click menu then my latestpost.txt data in load  a div.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <h2>DASHBOARD</h2>
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">BY INDUSTRY</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="button">DISTRIBUTION</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HEALTH CARE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">E-COMMERCE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">AUTOMOTIVE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MANUFACTURING</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HI-TECH</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">BY FUNCTIONS</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">SALES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FINANCE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">INVENTORY</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">OPERATIONS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PROCUREMENT</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
```

Now I have j jquery code , it's jquery working perfect when i am not using li or etc, but when i combine with li and ul it's dows not working

```
  <div class="col-md-10">
  <div id="content">
            <iframe src='https://sense-demo.qlik.com/single/?appid=133dab5d-8f56-4d40-b3e0-a6b401391bde&sheet=1ff88551-9c4d-41e0-b790-37f4c11d3df8&opt=currsel&select=clearall
' frameborder='0' width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>    
    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#content").load("latestpost.txt");

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: console log? In WordPress you should use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: Do you have a public URL of your site?

Comment: hamm added , but does not working

Comment: http://polestarllp.com/polestarnew/  click for dashboard you get all thing